# AddJsonFormatters in my ASP.NET MvcCore web app, is not setting the json settings correctly

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to manually define some json settings for my responses in an ASP.NET MVC Core web app. Given the following code, it does not work:

```
services.AddMvcCore()
        ... <snip a few services>
        .AddJsonFormatters(options => options = JsonHelpers.JsonSerializerSettings);
```

and

```
public static JsonSerializerSettings JsonSerializerSettings 
{
    get
    {
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
            Formatting = Formatting.None,
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include,
            DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat
        };

        settings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
        return settings;
    }
}
```

I'm assuming that I need to manually specify each setting, during setup. Not define the new instance of the settings instead. (I'll test this in a sec).

e.g.

```
services.AddMvcCore()
    .AddJsonFormatters(o =>
    {
        o.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        o.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
    });
```

So, why can't I use my instance instead of manually setting each property? My initial reasoning was that I uses these json settings in OTHER parts of my system, so I wanted to have one place to define the settings and any other places use that same instance. This way, I don't need to manually update multiple locations in the code.